# Using z test or t test when $\sigma$ is unknown

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, t-test, sampling, normality-assumption

*Note: I realize similar questions have been asked here before but I couldn't find my specific doubt addressed (not in so many words, anyway).*

In testing a large sample for the population mean if the standard deviation is not known we may use the z-test or the t-test. Is it correct to say that although the sampling distribution of the mean, i.e. $\bar {X}$, will be approximately normal by the Central Limit Theorem the statistic $t=s^{-1}(\bar{X}-\mu)$, converges to the sampling distribution of the mean, hence we ought to use the t-test?

Also, how can we prove that t always has the t distribution when the population isn't normal.

Comment: Several misunderstandings here. // Let's start with this, for normal data: If $\sigma$ is known, then always use $z;$ if $\sigma$ is unknown, estimated by $S,$ then always use $t.$ In the latter case, when $n$ becomes large, the critical values of a 2-sided test at 5% level will become very nearly $\pm 1.96$ (almost the same critical values as for $z.)$

Comment: My question is regarding the theoretical underpinnings of the same.

Comment: For normal data, $T = \frac{\bar X - \mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}} \sim \mathsf{T}(\nu=n-1).$ For increasing degrees of freedom $\nu,$ quantile 0.975 of $\mathsf{T}(\nu)$ converges to 1.96: In R, code `qt(.975, c(5,10,20,30,50,100,1000))` returns, respectively,
$2.570582, 2.228139, 2.085963, 2.042272, 2.008559, 1.983972, 1.962339.$

Comment: However, unless data are normal, $T_n = \frac{\bar X_n=\mu}{S_n/\sqrt{n}}$ does not necessarily approximate dist'n $\mathsf{T}(n-1),$ even for large $n,$ because numerator and denominator are not necessarily independent.  Sample mean $\bar X$ and sample variance $S^2$ are independent only for normal data.

Comment: In view of your last comment how do you justify using t test for non normal population?

Comment: Ok. Thanks. In the case when $\sigma$ is known but the sample size is small does trial & error justify the z-test too?(non normal)

Comment: "z interval should be OK via CLT" but in my previous comment I asked this in the context of a small sized sample, so how does CLT apply?